# Map array js - how to pass argument

Tags: javascript

If I write map like this:

```
days=['m', 't'];
days.map(paste(day));

function paste(day) {
  alert(day)
}
```

It doesn't work;

How can i pass my argument day to function paste?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass your `paste` function to map, not invoke it:

```
var days = ['m', 't'];
days.map(paste);

function paste(day) {
  alert(day)
}
```

`map` function will iterate through the `days` array and invoke the function you passed in it on every object of the `days`.

Comment: ty just found it on mdn

Answer (score 0):

```
days=['m', 't'];
days.map(function (a){paste(a)});

function paste(day) {
      alert(day)
}
```

This works but aga's is better. ( shorter).

However - notice cross platform issue
http://jsbin.com/axaluq/42?q=array%20map